# Calculate sentences using function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have come across a question about calculating sentences using a form in HTML, but I wanted to work out the function first to see if it would work. Here is my function that I have not been able to get it working in jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/jdloomis/fxt81ynu/2/):

```
var numSentences = 0;

function calSentences(longString) {
  var length = longString.length;
  var sentence = '';

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  sentence += longString[i];

  if (longString[i] == '.') {
    numSentences++;
    sentence = '';
    }
  }
}

console.log(calSentences("This is a sentence. My second sentence."));
```

I have been able to figure out most of the functions and what they do in my book except this one and a word count without using .split, I will post that one in another post if I cannot figure it out.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I forgot to return the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were **so** close with your attempt! All you forgot to do is **return** the number of sentences with `return numSentences`:

```js
var numSentences = 0;

function calSentences(longString) {
  var length = longString.length;
  var sentence = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    sentence += longString[i];
    if (longString[i] == '.') {
      numSentences++;
      sentence = '';
    }
  }

  return numSentences;
}

console.log(calSentences("This is a sentence. My second sentence."));
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you are not returning anything from your function.

Also, keep `var numSentences` local to your function, so that it's reset to `0` each time you run your function.  Otherwise, you are adding on to the previous calculation each time you run the function.

```js
function calSentences(longString) {
  var numSentences = 0;
  var length = longString.length;
  var sentence = '';

for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  sentence += longString[i];

  if (longString[i] == '.') {
    numSentences++;
    sentence = '';
    }
  }
  return numSentences;
}

console.log(calSentences("This is a sentence. My second sentence."));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and tip!!